# Ignore spaces, but allow text with spaces

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

I need to write a simple antlr4 grammar for expressions like this:

```
{paramName=simple text} //correct
{ paramName = simple text} //correct
{bad param=text} //incorrect
```

First two expression is almost equal. The difference is a space before and after parameter name. Third is incorrect, spaces not allowed in parameter name. I write a grammar:

```
grammar Test;

prog       : '{' paramName '=' paramValue '}' ;
paramName  : PARAM_NAME ;
paramValue : TEXT_WITH_SPACES ;

PARAM_NAME       : [A-Za-zА-Яа-я_] [A-Za-zА-Яа-я_0-9]* ;
TEXT_WITH_SPACES : (LETTERS_EN|' ')+ ;
WS               : [ ]+ -> skip;

fragment LETTERS_EN       : ([A-Za-z]) ;
```

So, the task is ignore spaces around parameter name, but allow spaces in parameter value. But when I add a space inside rule TEXT_WITH_SPACES, my second expression highlight as icorrect.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cwyh.jpg)

What can I do? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore all spaces, but consider them to be "end of word", and allow more words in the value:

```
grammar Test;

prog       : '{' paramName '=' paramValue '}' ;
paramName  : WORD ;
paramValue : WORD+ ;

WORD       : [A-Za-zА-Яа-я_] [A-Za-zА-Яа-я_0-9]* ;
WS         : [ ]+ -> skip;
```

---

Update: To preserve spaces in the value:

```
grammar Test;

prog       : '{' paramName '=' paramValue '}' ;
paramName  : WORD ;
paramValue : WORD | MULTIWORD ;

MULTIWORD  : WORD ((' ')+ WORD)* ;
WORD       : [A-Za-zА-Яа-я_] [A-Za-zА-Яа-я_0-9]* ;
WS         : [ ]+ -> skip;
```

This is based on `MULTIWORD` matching multiple words with nothing but space in between them, and other cases being matched by sequence of WORD and WS.

Comment: then we lost all extra spaces in value: for example "my phrase        with multiply spaces between phrase and with words" (can't write is here:)

Comment: In that case you might get away with using the fact that multiple words would be longer than a single word, i.e. match multiple words as one token and allow paramValue to either be a singleword or the multiword token.

Comment: wow, this seems correct, let me do some tests, before mark that as answer, but we need swap positions MULTIWORD and WORD

Comment: yeah, we loose all spaces in paramValue before the first word, but it is acceptable. Thank you!